# Validating XML files in Java against two schemas with same namespace

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have

1. an XML document,
2. base XSD file and
3. extended XSD file.

Both XSD files have one namespace.

File 3) includes file 2): `<xs:include schemaLocation="someschema.xsd"></xs:include>`

XML document (file 1) has following root tag:

```
<tagDefinedInSchema xmlns="http://myurl.com/myapp/myschema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://myurl.com/myapp/myschema schemaFile2.xsd">
```

where `schemaFile2.xsd` is the file 3 above.

I need to validate file 1 against both schemas, without

1. modifying the file itself and
2. merging two schemas in one file.

How can I do this in Java?

UPD: Here is the code I'm using.

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
        .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance();
documentFactory.setNamespaceAware(namespaceAware);
DocumentBuilder builder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData
        .getBytes("UTF-8")));

File schemaLocation = new File(schemaFileName);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaLocation);

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

Source source = new DOMSource(document);

validator.validate(source);
```

UPD 2: This works for me:

```
    public static void validate(final String xmlData,
        final String schemaFileName, final boolean namespaceAware)
        throws SAXException, IOException {
    final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
            .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(new MySchemaResolver());
    final Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema();

    final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.setResourceResolver(schemaFactory.getResourceResolver());

    final InputSource is = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData
            .getBytes("UTF-8")));
    validator.validate(new SAXSource(is), new SAXResult(new XMLReaderAdapter()));
}



class MySchemaResolver implements LSResourceResolver {

@Override
public LSInput resolveResource(final String type,
        final String namespaceURI, final String publicId, String systemId,
        final String baseURI) {
    final LSInput input = new DOMInputImpl();
    try {
        if (systemId == null) {
            systemId = SCHEMA1;
        }
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                new File("path_to_schema_directory/" + systemId));

        input.setByteStream(fis);
        return input;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("File Not found", ex);
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What mechanism are you using to parse the file?

Comment: I added the code to my question.

Comment: In your code schemaFileName should be schemaFile2.xsd (the extended XSD file), is that what you're doing?

Comment: I tried it, but when I do so, I get an error - tags defined in schema 1 are not found. I modified the code as shown above (UPD 2) and now it works.

Comment: What is SCHEMA1 in your 2nd update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of terminology: you have one schema here, which is built from two schema documents.

If you specify schemaFile2.xsd to the API when building the Schema, it should automatically pull in the other document via the xs:include. If you suspect that this isn't happening, you need to explain what the symptoms are that cause you to believe this.

Comment: It doesn't pull the included document. Symptom: I get an error message like "Definition of element X not found" and that element is defined in the included XSD. I already solved my problem (see above, UPD 2).

Answer (score 0):

It may seem a bit inefficient, but couldn't you validate against schema A, create a new validator using schema B and validate against that one too?

Comment: This doesn't work because the second schema includes the first one. When I validate the code against the second schema, the elements of the included schema are not found.

Comment: So the problem is that you are not sure how to refer to schema1 from schema2?